# Is there a way in Eclipse to organize projects into folders?

Tags: eclipse

The new folder command seems to create a folder *within* a folder. I have so many projects that they are hard to organize by name only. Is there an Eclipse better way?

Answer (score 3):

You can't put projects in to folders.

You can change the Package and Project explorer views to show 'Working Sets' as the top level elements in the view (use the view menu 'Top Level Elements' to do this - the view menu is the small down arrow at the top right of the view window).